# R: Creating a graph from a text file

Tags: r, linux, tshark

```
#!/bin/Rsceipt
skip.header  <- 11           # how many lines to skip including the header row
comment.char <- "="         # skip lines with <char> in it 
col.names    <- c( "time", "frames", "bytes" )
args <- commandArgs( trailingOnly = TRUE )
number.graphs <- length( args )

for ( d in 1:length( args ) ) {
    file      <- args[[d]]
    # get date and time from file name and convert to a time object
    date.time <- as.POSIXlt(
                   gsub(
                     ".*([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})_([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2}).*",
                     "\\1 \\2:\\3:00",
                     file,
                     perl=T
                   )
                 )
    # read the data
    traffic   <- read.table( file=file,
                             header=F,
                 sep="|",
                             col.names=col.names,
                             skip=skip.header,
                             comment.char="="
                           )
    # massage the data a bit

    traffic$kbits   <- ( traffic$bytes * 8 ) / 1024
    traffic$frames  <- NULL
    traffic$bytes   <- NULL
    traffic$time    <- as.numeric(
                         gsub(" <> .*", "", traffic$time, perl = T )
                       ) + date.time
    # calculate max and avg
    traffic.max <- round( max( traffic$kbits ), digits = 2 )
    traffic.avg <- round( mean( traffic$kbits ), digits = 2 )
    # prepare the graph
    sub.title <- paste( "Max:", traffic.max, "Kbit/s; Avg:", traffic.avg, "Kbit/s" )
    names( traffic )
    # output as pdf and png 
    pdf( paste( file, ".pdf", sep = "" ) )
    plot( traffic,  type="h", main=file, sub=sub.title, xlab="Time", ylab="Kbit/s" )
    png( paste( file, ".png", sep = "" ) )
    plot( traffic,  type="h", main=file, sub=sub.title, xlab="Time", ylab="Kbit/s" )
}
```

this is my code, currently for a text file with this format:

```
=============================
| IO Statistics             |
|                           |
| Duration: 4.643122 secs   |
| Interval: 1 secs          |
|                           |
| Col 1: Frames and bytes   |
|---------------------------|
|          |1               |
| Interval | Frames | Bytes |
|---------------------------|
  0 <> 1  |     21 |  1918 
  1 <> 2  |     24 |  4894 
  2 <> 3  |    491 |  5042 
  3 <> 4  |     34 |   402 
  4 <> Dur|     52 |   747 
=============================
```

it works perfectly, however, I need to make it work for a file with this format:

```
=============================
| IO Statistics             |
|                           |
| Duration: 4.643122 secs   |
| Interval: 1 secs          |
|                           |
| Col 1: Frames and bytes   |
|---------------------------|
|          |1               |
| Interval | Frames | Bytes |
|---------------------------|
|  0 <> 1  |     21 |  1918 |
|  1 <> 2  |     24 |  4894 |
|  2 <> 3  |    491 |  5042 |
|  3 <> 4  |     34 |   402 |
|  4 <> Dur|     52 |   747 |
=============================
```

no matter what I try, I am getting the error message :

> more columns than column names

I thought maybe removing the first and last char from

> traffic$time

will fix it, but I had no luck, maybe I am doing it wrong.

Comment: Try adding two place holder names to `col.names`? You're adding two `|` for each row, so maybe that's creating two extra columns, hence the thrown error.

Comment: @Mako212, Thanks for the response, if by that you mean :  col.names    <- c("a", "time", "frames", "bytes","b") , I tried that and I am getting the error : "line 1 did not have 5 elements"